# Filter by conditions for multiple columns in R

Tags: r, filter, conditional-statements

I need to filter by conditions when `Plan_Year` is `1 less than` `YEAR` and all rows of `NA` in CAT column.

I have the following code:

```
Table <- Table %>% filter(YEAR == Plan_Year+1)
```

How can I include/modify the code above to obtain all rows with NA in CAT column?

Thanks in advance.

Table:

```
YEAR     CAT      Plan_Year
1998     NA       NA
1998     125-1    1997    
1998     171-2    1997
1998     NA       NA  
.
.
2017     114-1    202
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `|` and `is.na`

```
Table %>% filter(YEAR == Plan_Year+1|is.na(CAT))
  YEAR   CAT Plan_Year
1 1998  <NA>        NA
2 1998 125-1      1997
3 1998 171-2      1997
4 1998  <NA>        NA
```

Or using base R

```
dt[which(dt$YEAR == (dt$Plan_Year + 1)|is.na(dt$CAT)),]
  YEAR   CAT Plan_Year
1 1998  <NA>        NA
2 1998 125-1      1997
3 1998 171-2      1997
4 1998  <NA>        NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `|` (or) to combine the two conditions:

```
Table %>% filter(YEAR == Plan_Year + 1 | is.na(CAT))
```

Comment: WOW~ so close :-)

Comment: if he wants to filter for both conditions, wouldn't he want `&` not `|`

Comment: @tbradley OP states *include rows with NA Cat Columns*, that would mean an *or* condition from my understanding.