# filter multiple columns together with criteria - R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have found plenty of similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938863/dplyr-filter-with-condition-on-multiple-columns),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46964091/filter-by-conditions-for-multiple-columns-in-r),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52546253/filter-value-in-multiple-columns-in-r) are some of them), but none of them answers the mine:

I have this data:

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(X = sample(1:10, 100, replace=TRUE),
                 Y = sample(11:90, 100, replace=TRUE),
                 Z = sample(1000:2000, 100, replace=TRUE),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
x <- data.frame(X = c(7, 5, 3, 9),
                     Y = c(14, 13, 19, 87),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Where `x` is a subset of `df` with specific grouping and computations. And now, I'm trying to filter `df` by both `x` columns. For example, for a specific row in `df`, it has to be `X=7` and `Y=14` to be `TRUE`, or `X=5` and `Y=13` to be `TRUE`, it has to be `FALSE` if `X=7` and `Y<>14`, and so on. So, the criteria has to consider both columns together. I have tried with this:

```
> df[df$X == x$X & df$Y == x$Y,]
   X  Y    Z
28 9 87 1071
```

And this gives me only one true value, when I know it has to be at least 4 (because `x` is a subset of `df`)

This is kind-of what I'm looking for (it gives me 0 rows):

```
df[df[,c("X","Y")] %in% x[,c("X","Y")],]
```

Expected Output:

```
   X  Y    Z
16 7 14 1632
28 9 87 1071
30 3 19 1297
38 7 14 1701
67 5 13 1323
77 9 87 1484
88 3 19 1951
```

Comment: Can yo show the expected output

Comment: @camille row index 16 and 38.

Comment: @akrun I already added the expected output

Comment: Okay, then the output seems to be matching with my solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be we need an `inner_join`

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df, x)
#  X  Y    Z
#1 7 14 1632
#2 9 87 1071
#3 3 19 1297
#4 7 14 1701
#5 5 13 1323
#6 9 87 1484
#7 3 19 1951
```

---

If we need the row names to match as well

```
df[do.call(paste, df[names(x)]) %in% do.call(paste, x),]
#   X  Y    Z
#16 7 14 1632
#28 9 87 1071
#30 3 19 1297
#38 7 14 1701
#67 5 13 1323
#77 9 87 1484
#88 3 19 1951
```